# SQL query - WHERE not working

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have got this query which works fine:

```
SELECT p.design_id, p.product_id, t.account_id, p.name, p.width, p.height, 
 p.price, t.email 
 FROM designs AS p
 INNER JOIN ( SELECT user_id, email, account_id FROM users ) AS t
 USING(user_id) ORDER BY p.design_id LIMIT 0, 300 );
```

Now I am trying to trim the result:

```
SELECT p.design_id, p.product_id, t.account_id, p.name, p.width, 
 p.height, p.price, t.email 
 FROM designs AS p
 INNER JOIN ( SELECT user_id, email, account_id FROM users 
 WHERE account_id = 0) AS t
 USING(user_id) ORDER BY p.design_id LIMIT 0, 3 );
```

But the second query result is exactly the same as the first one.

Please could somebody shine some light on this?

//UPDATE

I removed the php vaiables to stop the unnecessary confusion :)

Comment: It could be you need to place a namespace for the fields. aka WHERE t.account_id = $ind

Comment: Try putting `echo` in front of the string definitions to see the actual query that's sent.

Comment: why nesting the query on `users`?

Comment: @Rob, by adding t. query fails

Comment: @Quassnoi, I don;t know why, have you got a better idea ? :)

Comment: sure, not nesting it, like in @JohnWoo's answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

give this a try

```
"SELECT   p.design_id, p.product_id, t.account_id, 
          p.name, p.width, p.height, p.price, t.email 
 FROM     designs AS p
          INNER JOIN  users AS t
              ON p.user_id = t.user_ID AND
                 t.account_id = $ind
 ORDER BY p.design_id LIMIT " . $from . ", " . $howMany
```

Comment: weird. can you post sample data with desired result?

Comment: Your solution actualy works! There was also one more problem somewhere else. Thank you

Comment: Calculating a total before this query which was resulting in $from and $howMany getting wrong values

Answer (score 2):

*Why don't you try using a placeholder in the where condition too as like below or was it a typo.*

```
"SELECT p.design_id, p.product_id, t.account_id, p.name, p.width, p.height, p.price, t.email 
 FROM designs AS p
 INNER JOIN ( SELECT user_id, email, account_id FROM users WHERE account_id = **".$ind."**) AS t
 USING(user_id) ORDER BY p.design_id LIMIT ".$from.", ".$howMany );
```

Answer (score 2):

You have not selected column **user_id** from **designs**.  Your JOIN is not working at all.  From the manual:

> The USING(column_list) clause names a list of columns that must exist in both tables.

Or all the users have account_id = 0 (or at least all the users that have designs).

If it's neither of those, try removing the word 'AS' before your nested select table 't'.

You could also try it without USING, use "ON t.user_id = p.user_id" instead of "USING(user_id)"